# landing at error section of jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to call a REST webservice using Ajax like the following :

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:9090/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data); 
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("some error"); 
                }
            });
```

And it's always giving me `some error` message. I have tested the webservice using `curl` in PHP and it works fine. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Please write down error here.

Comment: It's reaching `alert("some error"); ` and showing it in the alert box. I don't see any error in the alert though.

Comment: write console.log(data) before alert. it will display error

Comment: @GufranHasan On the console, I am seeing `GET http://localhost:9090/JAX-RS_examples/rest/HelloWorld/sayHello net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: Add dataType: "jsonp", just after url parameter

Comment: "And it's always giving me `some error` message"...well to be fair that's what you told it to do when an error occurred. The real error is hiding in your console and network tools. You _could_ get at it by looking at `data` (which is actually an XHR object) but you chose not to. Reporting that the application displays the totally arbitrary error message you explicitly instructed it to is neither surprising, nor interesting, nor helpful to anyone diagnosing the problem (including you)

Comment: Anyway I'd guess at a CORS error, especially if it worked using cURL.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like CORS error.